# Why is list-style-image from parent overriding child's image?

Tags: html, css, list

This is my HTML:

```
<ul id="todoList" class="workList">
    <li>
         <h2 class="collapse"> Release 1</h2> 
        <ul>
            <ul> <strong> Core Additions </strong>

                <li class="workDone">Done -- should be checked off</li>
                <li class="workDone">Done</li>
                <li>Not Done</li>
                <li>Not Done</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the conflicting code:

```
.workDone {
    color: #A0A0A0;
    font-weight: lighter;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: url("..//images/checkMark.png");
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.workList > li > ul li {
    margin-left: 32px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    list-style-image: url("..//images/checkBox.png");
}
```

`workDone` is the child -- I placed it in front to see if the position it was declared was the problem.

`.workList` is an un-ordered list and `.workDone` is an `<li>`

For some reason google chrome shows `.workDone`'s checkMark.png crossed off and it then inherits it's parent's image ...

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7guf2/10/)

Why is this happening?
Is there a work around/Solution?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML to make the structure very clear you are applying this CSS to.

Comment: try using .workDone > li. BTW, without a fiddle can't help you much.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl It's generated with javascript ajax ... I'll post a jsFiddle with what I can.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew: After the ajax call when the relevant HTML is in your page, open the debugger console or right-click your element in the page and click "Inspect Element". On the Debugger's element tab you can see the actual mark up of interest as it is generated. You can copy-paste that into your question.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl , Thanks for your time -- I did that but I had to clean it up. I think jsfiddle could have done that for me with the "tidy up" though.. Yikes. I just posted the fiddle as of now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.workList > li > ul  li
```

is a more specific CSS selector than

```
.workDone
```

if I understand correctly you are looking for this:

```
.workList > li > ul  li.workDone
{
    color: #A0A0A0 ;
    font-weight: lighter;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: url("..//images/checkMark.png") ;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Yes! I actually just found the solution on one of the related suggestions ... I guess I should delete this question.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew: No need to delete the question as it could be useful to future users with similar issues.